# Scala: is there an helper to get an Option[String] if the string is null?

Tags: java, scala, nullpointerexception, null, helper

This is a really simple question but I can't find the thing I'm looking for anywhere:

Is there an helper somewhere in Scala that does this?

```
  def stringOption(string: String): Option[String] =
      if (string == null) None else Some(string)
```

I'm copy-pasting more-or-less the same code everywhere I have to use Java libraries.

It simply convert the String to an Option[String] if the String is actually `null`. Many methods in many libraries in Java tends to return `null` when it can't return anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply:

```
def stringOption(string: String): Option[String] = Option(string)
```

Therefore the function is not really useful as it is equivalent to calling `Option.apply` right away.

Comment: Ahhh \o/ Many thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! Good thing you asked :)

Comment: @Cecile don't forget to accept this excellent answer if its correct

Comment: Yes I'm trying but it seems I have to wait 10 min after the question as been asked :)

Answer (score 1):

[@Jeans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38460662/1870803) will work in case the string is `null`. If you also want to make sure it's not *empty*, a little extension method can help

```
implicit class RichString(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
  def toOpt(): Option[String] = Option(s).filter(_.trim.nonEmpty)
}
```

And now you do:

```
val option = "hello, world!".toOpt()
```

Comment: A better scala way would yet be: ``def lift(): Option[String] = Option(s).filter(_.trim.nonEmpty)``

Comment: @JeanLogeart Definitely looks better. Thanks for the improvement!

Comment: Yes but I'm really testing only the `null` thingy. Thanks also because it may become useful.